# Entities with very large collections of large objects that you never want to hydrate - what is the recommended pattern?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many

We are using nhibernate and we have a lot of one-to-many and many-to-many relationships where hydrating the many side fully (with a ToList, Where, or other iteration) would result in a huge performance hit. Better to force our developers to make deliberate calls to the database to get just the entities they need for processing.

What is the recommended pattern here?

We've considered making the getter private and having nhibernate ignore it so that only the many side (child) has the relationship information. We've also considered having the getter just throw a "not allowed" exception.

In general I think the question is, how do you model this so it is correct, but also discourage developers making calls that hydrate very large collections fully?

As an example, imagine a `Store` entity with a collection of `Customers`. You probably never want all those customers in memory. So how would you model this?

Comment: It is not gonna help, but you are doing this wrong. There are no many to many relationships in DDD. Relationships among entities (inside an aggregate) are one to one or one to many. An aggregate can only be referenced by another aggregate using its ID (no foreign key). Remember, in a perfect world aggregates are in different databases/services. Also, in a large app, if you use the same data model (i.e. database) for reading and writing data. You end up with a spaghetti mess really quick (see CQRS). According to Greg Young, DDD can't be done properly without CQRS.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas Yeah we are starting to see this. More and more our reads are divorcing from our CUD and domain model. Ok so no many to many...but we have lot's of one-to-many relationships where the many side is prohibitively large. What to do then?

Comment: Try to slowly draw a line between read and write by first doing it in code even if this line doesn't exist in stored data (this can comes later). Move all reading logic out of your aggregates/entities into read entities (aka. projections). At first you can use SQL views to populate these projections. Use one projection by page or section of the app you want to display. Remember projections are driven by the user interface. By doing this you will be able to fetch only the data you want to display.

Comment: As of write side, load in memory only the data needed to validate the user command. A command is made against aggregates only (not entities). To validate a command the aggregate is loaded in memory with all its entities. In you case if you never need `Customers` to validate commands against `Store` maybe it's two separate aggregates, but you're the one knowing the domain so it's up to you too answer this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such things as Associations in DDD. Your problem statement's inherent issue - that prevents you from successfully modeling the domain - is that the storage concepts (like associations) are leaking into the domain model.

Even though the data will eventually be persisted in the form of one-to-one or one-to-many relationships, thinking in associations corrupts the thought process.

A few DDD rules before we discuss possible solutions:

**1. Aggregates are Transaction Boundaries.**

An aggregate is a cluster of associated objects considered as a single unit. All enclosed objects within the aggregate are loaded and persisted together to guarantee that Business Invariants are always satisfied.

If you have an aggregate that encloses 1000 entities, you have to load all of them into memory. So it follows that Smaller Aggregates are better.

**2. Aggregates are Cohesive Wholes.**

Put another way, Aggregates represent distinct concepts in the domain.

Behavior associated with more than one Aggregate is usually an aggregate by itself with its own set of attributes, enclosed objects, and behavior. Favoriting or Bookmarking is a good example.

**3. There are usually no requirements for two-way linkages.**

The use case decides the direction of the relationship.

As an example use case, the point of maintaining article bookmarks might only be to show whether the user has already bookmarked the article. It would make sense to store the article's ID as part of the user (there would be very few) than to store the list of User IDs who bookmarked the article as part of the article.

**4. You can have infinite Read Models.**

Domain Models are only for the "write" side of the application. Aggregates only deal with organizing data and enforcing constraints on the "write" side of the domain.

You are free to rewire the data any way you want, in multiple forms, on the read side. For example, you can have a subscriber listen to the Favorited Domain Events (raised after processing the Favorite Commands) and build a composite data structure containing data from both the User and the Article aggregates.

**A few possible solutions to your problem:**

1. If an aggregate encloses huge data of an entity, promote the entity to be an aggregate.
2. Evaluate the direction of the use case and see if the number of enclosed entity objects can be reduced.
3. Construct a read model with the right data structure in a different layer so that the "write" side can be simplified. This is only possible if there are no business invariants, or you can use corrective policies to validate data in the background.

If you have concrete examples or use cases that are troubling you and discuss them, please add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather say that aggregate roots (AR) are *consistency* boundaries.  This does make them a good fit to transactions but keeping a single AR change to a transactions is something that one certainly should strive for but, for me anyway, is not a hard-and-fast rule.

You typically would not need an entire, large, collection to be loaded as part of an aggregate in order for the aggregate to be consistent.  For something like an `Order` -> `Order.Line` you would but in such cases one typically would not have a prohibitively large collection.

In cases where you *do* find that you "need" the collection you may find the reference quite weak and you could benefit from distilling some property of the collection that is useful in determining the consistency, e.g. `Count`, or `TotalCost`.  You repository would be responsible for determining this property on hydration.

I never use an ORM for my own domains since they do tend to muddy the waters, especially w.r.t. lazy-loading and "navigation" through the object graph.  An aggregate is a whole and should be loaded and altered in its entirety.

The domain should not be used for querying but only for the transactional/write side of your implementation.

In order to read data a simple and direct query mechanism of sorts has served me well.

Comment: Thanks @Eben Roux. And what about when you are manipulating the domain? Should reads still be not through the domain?

Comment: @richard There would be very few cases where loading an aggregate would provide you with everything you need to render a view.  You would end up looking at lazy-loading and the like which is a red flag IMHO.  Whenever an object has to go *over-the-wire* (serialized/deserialized) then a domain object would be more effort than it is worth.  Read models can be exposed using an approach as close to your data as possible.  This is why ORMs add very little value to *my* DDD projects.